# <vector> is messing up my Quicksort

Tags: c++, vector, quicksort

I have to implement quicksort in C++. I wanted to use `std::vector` for my quicksort algorithm because I'm going to be reading in a load of numbers from a text file and the dynamic sizing would be useful. However, when I tried to implement quicksort with a vector instead of an array it didn't work and I'm at a loss to explain why.

Also, one of my functions stopped printing to the console when I used the vector implementation. I tried the code with an array and it works fine, but I would really prefer to use a vector.

Here's the code: (note that this is just the algorithm itself, not any of the text file stuff)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void QuickSort(vector<double>, int, int);
int splitVector(vector<double>, int, int);
void swap(int &, int &);

void main(){

    vector<double> myVector;

    myVector.insert(myVector.end(), 2);
    myVector.insert(myVector.end(), 6);
    myVector.insert(myVector.end(), 5);
    myVector.insert(myVector.end(), 9);
    myVector.insert(myVector.end(), 3);

    QuickSort(myVector, 0, myVector.size()-1);

    for(vector<double>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); it++)
        cout<<*it<<" ";

    cout<<endl<<endl;

}

void QuickSort(vector<double> list, int low, int high){

    if((high-low) > 1){

    int splitIndex = splitVector(list, low, high);

    QuickSort(list, low, splitIndex-1); //left subarray
    QuickSort(list, splitIndex+1, high);


    }

}

int splitVector(vector<double> list, int low, int high){

    int left = low+1;
    int right = high;

    double pivot = list[low];

    while(left <= right){

        while(list[left] < pivot && left <= right){ 
                left++;
        }

        while(list[right] > pivot && right >= left){
                right--;
        }

        if((right - left) > 0){
                swap(list[left], list[right]);
        }

    }

    swap(list[low], list[left-1]);

    return left-1;  //resting place of the pivot

}

void swap(int &first, int &second){     

    cout<<"Swapping..."<<endl<<endl;

    int temp = first;

    first = second;

    second = temp;

}
```

The "Swapping..." part of `swap()` is the part that doesn't output for me, but I tested the function itself in the main and it seems to swap elements in the vector fine. I'm pretty new to vectors, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just a comment: you do know about the existence of [std::vector::push_back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), right?

Comment: `myVector.push_back(2)` is the conventional way of doing what you do with `myVector.insert(myVector.end(), 2)`. Just saying.

Comment: @Streppel Nope. I suppose that's important?

Comment: @Radix: it's not important to this question, but it is important for programming in general to know your standard libraries and how to use them best.

Comment: Also, your `swap` function is unneeded, there's already `std::swap` which is almost the same, but better.  But it doesn't report to cout.

Comment: Interestingly it isn't actually vector that's being weird with your code, it's the _array_ that's behaving weird.  Array parameters are passed to functions as pointers to the data, which makes it behave _as if_ it were passed by reference.  No other type does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You meant to pass your vector by reference instead of value so the original can be changed: `vector<double>& list` instead of `vector<double> list`.

Also I highly suggest not to use standard container names like `list` as parameter names.

Comment: That was it. I assumed that vectors would automatically be passed by reference like arrays, but I guess I should have done my research. Thanks!

Comment: @Radix: it would be incorrect to say arrays are passed by reference. Since a C++ array is technically a pointer to some memory location, you can modify that location even though you can't modify the pointer itself (i. e. _which_ location it's pointing to). If it was passed by reference, you would be able to modify the pointer itself.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe You are right of course. I suppose I was referencing the functional implications of passing by reference as opposed to the actual memory aspect.